# C# проблема подключения к серверу через прокси

Tags: c#, proxy, клиент-сервер, сервер

Пытаюсь установить соединение через прокси, посылаю ему :

```
CONNECT 61.76.87.98:730 HTTP/1.0
Host: 61.76.87.98:730
```

Дело в том, что некоторые прокси возвращают :

> Ошибка протокола HTTP, Статус:503 Service Unavailable.

Все другие соединения работают с прокси нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некоторые прокси-серверы запрещают использование метода `CONNECT`, а те которые разрешают, могут разрешать `CONNECT` только на 443 порт.

Comment: Да, действительно, Вы правы, на порт 443 соединение проходит.

Но что если порт занят или необходимо открыть несколько приложений на разных портах сервера?

Comment: А на запросы GET подобная практика не распространяется?